# How to save the file with a json response

Tags: python-3.x, openxml

response gets a json of something like this:

```
{'additionalErrors': None,
 'data': {'contentType': 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet',
          'file': 'UEsDBBQACAAIAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAATAAAAeGwvdGhlbWUvdGhlbWUxLnhtbOyZz2/bNhT...
          (there are still about 11k characters)
          ...hsL3N0eWxlcy54bWxQSwUGAAAAAAsACwDGAgAASB4AAAAA',
          'name': 'export-data.xlsx'},
 'error': False,
 'errorText': ''}
```

Is it possible, having this data, to download the file to a computer?

I don't know how to solve this problem

Comment: It's base64, because json can't contain pure bytes. 

So: grab this element, decode b64, open file with "wb" (writing bytes) mode and just write it.

Answer (score 1):

You already downloaded the file when you get this response, it's just encoded in base64 format. To decode it, you can do this:

```py
import base64

resp = ... # get your JSON response

decoded = base64.b64decode(resp["data"]["file"])
with open("/some/path", "wb") as f:
    f.write(decoded)
```